# How can i save the email password logins so dnt need to enter again and again?

Tags: email, javascript

`How can save email password in browser of login page?

i have made login page with react js and whenever i login it i have to put email password details again and again. i want to save email password so next time it should not ask me to fill details. i have api of site and also email password. i need perfect and easy solution.

here is my code

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import  Login  from './Login';
import Products from './Products'
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
<BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
      
        <Route path='/' element={<Login/>}></Route>
        <Route path='/product' element={<Products/>}></Route>
        
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      
   
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

login.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import axios from "axios";

const Login = () => {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState ("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState ("")
  const [tokenValue, setTokenValue] = useState ("")
 


let Handle = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if(email === '' || password === ''){
    alert("empty form")
  }
  else{
    axios.post('https://api.store.ellcart.com/users/login', {
      email,password })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      alert('login successful')
      setTokenValue(response.data.authorisation.access_token)
      
    })
    .catch(function (error) 
    {
      console.log(error);
      alert('wrong credentials')
    });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello");
    if(tokenValue !== ''){
      localStorage.setItem("ElcartUserToken", tokenValue);
     
    }
  } , [tokenValue])

}
 

  

  return (

    <>
    <div className="container pt-4 md-4">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <form action="#" className="contact-form">
            <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mb-3">
              <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Cart" className="cart-image" />
              <h5 className="title ml-2 text-center">Sign Up</h5>
            </div>

            <div>
              <input
                type="email"
                className="form-control rounded border-white mb-3 form-input"
                placeholder="Email"
                value={email}
                required
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>

            <div>
              <input
                type="password"
                value={password}
                className="form-control rounded border-white mb-3 form-input"
                placeholder="Password"
                required
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="submit-button-wrapper">
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={Handle} />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div className="col-md-6 pt-4 drk">
          <div className="DarkPanel text-center">
            <h1>Ellcart</h1>
            <p>
              Omni Channel Ecommerce store management platform which
              simplifies, centralizes, and automates store management tasks,
              shipping process, marketing, and reporting.
            </p>

            <p className="joinedLine">
              More than 17k people joined us, it's your turn
            </p>
            <h6>&copy; Nest Software Private Limited.</h6>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  );

  }
export default  Login
```

producst.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';


function Products() {

  let [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem("ElcartUserToken"));

  let [allProducts, setallProducts] = useState();
  let [datacame, setdatacame] = useState(false);
  

  useEffect(() => {

    axios
      .get('https://api.store.ellcart.com/stores/70082/products', {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `token ${token}`
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        setallProducts(response.data)
        setdatacame(true)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        alert('failed')
        console.log(error);
      })
  }, []);

  console.log(allProducts);

  return (

    <>

      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Regular Price</th>
            <th>Sale Price</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            datacame ? allProducts.map((product, i) =>
            (
              <tr key={i}>
                <td>{product.product.name}</td>
                <td>{product.product.sku}</td>
                <td>{product.product.category_id}</td>
                <td>{product.product.regular_price}</td>
                <td>{product.product.sale_price}</td>
                <td>{product.product.stock_status}</td>
                <td>  <div class="dropdown" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                  <button class="btn" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span className="bi bi-three-dots-vertical"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                    
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit </a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                </td>

              </tr>)
            ) : "loadingg"
          }
        </tbody>
      </Table>

       </>

  )
}

export default Products;
```

`